# Difference between working at a constant rate and exerting a constant force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, work, power

Let's assume that two trains of equal masses are moving along parallel paths. The engine of train 1 exerts a constant force, and the engine of train 2 works at a constant rate. If in time $t$ they have the same velocity $v$ then who has traveled the larger distance?

Comment: Constant masses means that constant force implies constant acceleration. Constant power then means non-constant acceleration, but KE$\,=Pt$, and you can work out everything you need.